# Badge for Gitlab pipeline can't ignore skipped ones

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

According to [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#display-only-non-skipped-status) I could display a pipeline badge and ignoring the skipped pipelines with this snippet

```
https://gitlab.example.com/<namespace>/<project>/badges/<branch>/pipeline.svg?ignore_skipped=true
```

But this snippet always diplays a badge with status `unknown`. What did I miss?

Comment: There is currently an open bug [gitlab-org/gitlab#326513](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/326513) for the issue you are describing.

Comment: Does your branch have a recent pipeline _for_ that ref? If you just created the branch, but it has no (non-skipped) pipelines created by pushing to that branch, this can happen.

Comment: @sytech yes I have several pipelines.